# rolling checksums in the rsync algorithm

Tags: algorithm, rsync, matching

I'm trying to understand how [the rsync algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) works with respect to rolling checksums and blocks that match in a staggered fashion.

The wikipedia page seems to suggest that the sender and receiver both calculate and exchange rolling checksums for all possible blocks. But that would mean sending essentially one checksum per byte! I must be missing something. How does it work to be able to align blocks?

e.g. if S = 16 byte blocks, and the sender has this text for file A:

> The quick brown fox jumps over the
>   lazy dogs

and the receiver has this text for file B:

> The quick brown fox jumped over the
>   lazy dog

how would an rsync exchange work?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The receiver computes and sends rolling checksums only for non overlapping blocks.
The sender on the contrary computes it for every *possible* block (but keep the result local). Then for the sender, it's just a matter of checking if one of the non overlapping block (sent by the receiver) match with *any* (overlapping) local block.

Your example is too simple to see anything interesting, the two last blocks simply won't match and will be sent for merging.

With a more interesting example (uppercase is a block):

sender:

```
A B Cabc D
```

receiver:

```
A B C D
```

The receiver will send the MD5 and rolling hash for A, B, C and D.
The sender will compute the rolling hash for *every* (overlapping) block, it will match for A, for B, for C and for D. Since `abc` isn't match it will send it with the information where to merge it.

Comment: oh, I must have misread the bit about the receiver not sending all the checksums. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

(I'm working on a remote-synchronization problem myself right now, and @tonfa gives a good answer but I found their example a tad confusing. So I offer my own example, using Lorem Ipsum text as an example of the data being synchronized. <sub>I note that human-readable-text files can have their sentance/paragraph structure extracted for *domain-specific* synchronization optimizations, we aren't doing that: as far as `rsync` and the rolling-hash algorithm is concerned, every file is an opaque binary blob without any structure)</sub>

---

**Supposing a fileserver (`Alice`) has this file 641 byte: `lipsum.txt`**:

(Assume ASCII or UTF-8 encoding. Line-wraps at column 80 have been added for readability, the line-breaks would not be present in the actual file)

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla nisl enim,
consectetur quis quam consequat, pharetra tempus enim. Fusce iaculis libero
vitae ipsum accumsan efficitur. Fusce iaculis est et justo sollicitudin, sed
porttitor augue sagittis. Mauris aliquam nisl nibh, sed tempus magna venenatis
ac. Curabitur molestie nisl elit, suscipit egestas ex aliquam ac. Donec
dignissim, mauris nec malesuada pellentesque, ipsum sem porttitor est, quis
laoreet urna orci a leo. Cras tincidunt porttitor sapien, quis cursus metus
pulvinar id. Pellentesque nec mollis eros. Fusce sagittis vehicula ligula, nec
ullamcorper sapien sagittis non.
```

And supposing a remote client (`Bob`) has a slightly modified copy of `lipsum.txt`:

```
Proin finibus ullamcorper ante sit amet egestas. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla nisl enim, consectetur quis quam consequat,
pharetra tempus enim. Fusce iaculis libero vitae ipsum accumsan efficitur.
Fusce iaculis est et justo sollicitudin, sed porttitor augue sagittis. Mauris
aliquam nisl nibh, sed tempus magna venenatis ac. Nulla ex metus, malesuada
eget ultricies vel, fermentum quis nisl. Etiam ac venenatis tellus. Curabitur
molestie nisl elit, suscipit egestas ex aliquam ac. Donec dignissim, mauris nec
malesuada pellentesque, ipsum sem porttitor est, quis laoreet urna orci a leo.
Cras tincidunt porttitor sapien, quis cursus metus pulvinar id. Pellentesque
nec mollis eros.
```

Here's a visual `diff` for reference:

[image]

---

With rsync, it doesn't matter which host (computer) is running the server or client software, what matters is who the *sender* is and who the *receiver* is (as an rsync server can send and receive, and an rsync client can also send and receive). For this demonstration, the remote client (`Bob`) is *sending* its modified copy of `lipsum.txt` to the rsync server (`Alice`).

### Part 1: Receiver (Alice) sends existing file's fixed block hashes to sender (Bob):

Alice breaks-up `lipsum.txt` into equally sized blocks (for this demonstration lets use 32-byte sized blocks) and computes the *weak* hashes (checksums) of those blocks using the *weak* **rolling hash** of that block (note that the rolling-hash algorithm is *not* computed across block boundaries yet):

```
block offset     32-byte block bytes (as ASCII)       block weak-hash (as UInt32)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  0    |Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cons|    3262843843 
 16    |ectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla n|    1213926365 
 32    |isl enim, consectetur quis quam |    3307146210 
 48    |consequat, pharetra tempus enim.|    1702104107 
 64    |Fusce iaculis libero vitae ipsu |     113380311 
 80    |m accumsan efficitur. Fusce iacu|    3788835775 
 96    |lis est et justo sollicitudin, s|    2668366836 
112    |ed porttitor augue sagittis. Mau|     212601872 
128    |ris aliquam nisl nibh, sed tempu|    3149335490 
144    |s magna venenatis ac. Curabitur |    1050020743 
160    |molestie nisl elit, suscipit ege|     726010903 
176    |stas ex aliquam ac. Donec dignis|     169282427 
192    |sim, mauris nec malesuada pellen|    1806109673 
208    |tesque, ipsum sem porttitor est,|    1415646245 
224    | quis laoreet urna orci a leo. C|    1034619651 
240    |ras tincidunt porttitor sapien, |    4085386299 
256    |quis cursus metus pulvinar id. P|    4195748849 
272    |ellentesque nec mollis eros. Fus|    3458665474 
288    |ce sagittis vehicula ligula, nec|    3870297057 
304    | ullamcorper sapien sagittis non|    2035682393 
320    |.|                                      3014702
```

`Alice` then sends these block offsets and weak-hashes to `Bob`.

In this example, the block-size of 32 bytes with 32-bit sized hashes means Alice sends 84 bytes to Bob to represent a 641 byte-sized file - or about 13% of the size of the file that Bob wants to send. (Note that `rsync` uses block sizes sized in the *hundreds of bytes*, so the ratio is even smaller in real-life, making it very practical for slow connection speeds).

### Part 2: Sender (Bob) computes *rolling hashes* for a moving-window through their file:

First, Bob receives the hashes from Alice and loads them into a hashtable for `O(1)` lookup (yes, this means there's a "hash-of-a-hash").

Then the *real-magic* happens: Bob computes the rolling-hash of the 32-byte-sized window through their file. Bob's file is 714 bytes long, which means 682 hashes will be computed. `rsync`'s weak-hash algorithm is specifically designed to work on a rolling-basis (such that you can push-and-pop individual byte values) instead of reiterating the window on every byte (i.e. rsync does it in `O(n)` time instead of `O(n * m)` time, where `n` is the size of the file and `m` is the window size).

This is what Bob generates (showing the first 100 blocks for brevity):

```
Offset| 32-byte block bytes (as ASCII) | Weak-hash
-------------------------------------------------
    0 |Proin finibus ullamcorper ante s| 3787000889 
    1 |roin finibus ullamcorper ante si| 2983660626 
    2 |oin finibus ullamcorper ante sit| 1966279764 
    3 |in finibus ullamcorper ante sit |  663751685 
    4 |n finibus ullamcorper ante sit a| 3578072061 
    5 | finibus ullamcorper ante sit am|  757926908 
    6 |finibus ullamcorper ante sit ame| 1417546817 
    7 |inibus ullamcorper ante sit amet|  382274639 
    8 |nibus ullamcorper ante sit amet | 2866482182 
    9 |ibus ullamcorper ante sit amet e| 2888829949 
   10 |bus ullamcorper ante sit amet eg| 1780157435 
   11 |us ullamcorper ante sit amet ege|  763694078 
   12 |s ullamcorper ante sit amet eges| 1458113532 
   13 | ullamcorper ante sit amet egest| 2940865533 
   14 |ullamcorper ante sit amet egesta|  206310462 
   15 |llamcorper ante sit amet egestas|  539757628 
   16 |lamcorper ante sit amet egestas.| 1384516606 
   17 |amcorper ante sit amet egestas. | 1941179314 
   18 |mcorper ante sit amet egestas. L| 4284812189 
   19 |corper ante sit amet egestas. Lo| 3270773663 
   20 |orper ante sit amet egestas. Lor| 4045278126 
   21 |rper ante sit amet egestas. Lore| 2546076580 
   22 |per ante sit amet egestas. Lorem| 4200926111 
   23 |er ante sit amet egestas. Lorem | 4163898191 
   24 |r ante sit amet egestas. Lorem i| 2578123603 
   25 | ante sit amet egestas. Lorem ip| 2996308817 
   26 |ante sit amet egestas. Lorem ips| 4092857252 
   27 |nte sit amet egestas. Lorem ipsu| 1856506808 
   28 |te sit amet egestas. Lorem ipsum| 2946436023 
   29 |e sit amet egestas. Lorem ipsum | 1533676387 
   30 | sit amet egestas. Lorem ipsum d|  483134306 
   31 |sit amet egestas. Lorem ipsum do|  476908465 
   32 |it amet egestas. Lorem ipsum dol|  320277418 
   33 |t amet egestas. Lorem ipsum dolo| 3243707312 
   34 | amet egestas. Lorem ipsum dolor| 1496386478 
   35 |amet egestas. Lorem ipsum dolor | 3433761710 
   36 |met egestas. Lorem ipsum dolor s| 1480264640 
   37 |et egestas. Lorem ipsum dolor si| 1083640764 
   38 |t egestas. Lorem ipsum dolor sit|  232393675 
   39 | egestas. Lorem ipsum dolor sit | 3691055991 
   40 |egestas. Lorem ipsum dolor sit a| 4223208376 
   41 |gestas. Lorem ipsum dolor sit am| 1521290176 
   42 |estas. Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame| 4025158590 
   43 |stas. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet| 1003228109 
   44 |tas. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,| 1503267718 
   45 |as. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, | 3582200626 
   46 |s. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, c| 3172993844 
   47 |. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, co| 3615230768 
   48 | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, con| 3300133744 
   49 |Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cons| 3262843843 
   50 |orem ipsum dolor sit amet, conse| 4056353756 
   51 |rem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec| 2500266960 
   52 |em ipsum dolor sit amet, consect| 2453212114 
   53 |m ipsum dolor sit amet, consecte| 3549891538 
   54 | ipsum dolor sit amet, consectet| 3963358169 
   55 |ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetu|  379456558 
   56 |psum dolor sit amet, consectetur| 3206351927 
   57 |sum dolor sit amet, consectetur | 2648968167 
   58 |um dolor sit amet, consectetur a| 3918072789 
   59 |m dolor sit amet, consectetur ad| 3511225284 
   60 | dolor sit amet, consectetur adi| 2267089856 
   61 |dolor sit amet, consectetur adip| 2145979408 
   62 |olor sit amet, consectetur adipi| 2017070101 
   63 |lor sit amet, consectetur adipis| 1143409689 
   64 |or sit amet, consectetur adipisc| 3407809552 
   65 |r sit amet, consectetur adipisci| 3452242954 
   66 | sit amet, consectetur adipiscin| 1381174278 
   67 |sit amet, consectetur adipiscing| 3012037709 
   68 |it amet, consectetur adipiscing |  863898618 
   69 |t amet, consectetur adipiscing e| 1819020278 
   70 | amet, consectetur adipiscing el| 1786383342 
   71 |amet, consectetur adipiscing eli| 3535604791 
   72 |met, consectetur adipiscing elit| 2849705034 
   73 |et, consectetur adipiscing elit.| 3906866187 
   74 |t, consectetur adipiscing elit. | 3028814790 
   75 |, consectetur adipiscing elit. N| 1042025376 
   76 | consectetur adipiscing elit. Nu| 3860663273 
   77 |consectetur adipiscing elit. Nul| 2577534005 
   78 |onsectetur adipiscing elit. Null| 3386641470 
   79 |nsectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla| 1332743216 
   80 |sectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla | 2328497122 
   81 |ectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla n| 1213926365 
   82 |ctetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ni| 2679376865 
   83 |tetur adipiscing elit. Nulla nis| 1645546481 
   84 |etur adipiscing elit. Nulla nisl| 1719798761 
   84 |etur adipiscing elit. Nulla nisl| 1719798761 
   85 |tur adipiscing elit. Nulla nisl | 3454143396 
   86 |ur adipiscing elit. Nulla nisl e| 3142519701 
   87 |r adipiscing elit. Nulla nisl en| 3224963982 
   88 | adipiscing elit. Nulla nisl eni|  579210117 
   89 |adipiscing elit. Nulla nisl enim|  907021266 
   90 |dipiscing elit. Nulla nisl enim,| 1625361309 
   91 |ipiscing elit. Nulla nisl enim, |  804916057 
   92 |piscing elit. Nulla nisl enim, c| 3002403667 
   93 |iscing elit. Nulla nisl enim, co| 1436224338 
   94 |scing elit. Nulla nisl enim, con| 1020398423 
   95 |cing elit. Nulla nisl enim, cons| 2978286423 
   96 |ing elit. Nulla nisl enim, conse|   62524249 
   97 |ng elit. Nulla nisl enim, consec| 2620984147 
   98 |g elit. Nulla nisl enim, consect| 1986661209 
   99 | elit. Nulla nisl enim, consecte|  460917591
```

You might notice something special about Bob's **block 49**: it matches Alice's block 0 exactly (both have the ASCII bytes for "`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cons`" but they also share the hash value of `3262843843`!).

Bob then continues, byte-by-byte, noting which blocks also match those in Alice's copy (this is possible in `O(1)` time for each block, or `O(n)` in total) because Bob loaded Alice's block hashes into a hashtable.

There also exists an optimization: if Bob sees one of his block matches, he can jump-forward to the next integral block and see if that matches and so skip the intervening blocks if it's a match (so we know the 32-byte block at offset 49 matches, so we can skip to block 81 - and block 81 also matches (with hash `1213926365`, so jump to block 113, and so on...) ).

Keep doing this for all windows in Bob and eventually you'll get this output:

```
Offset   Bytes (as ASCII text)
----------------------------------------------
   49  |Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cons| 
   81  |ectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla n| 
  113  |isl enim, consectetur quis quam | 
  145  |consequat, pharetra tempus enim.| 
  177  | Fusce iaculis libero vitae ipsu| 
  209  |m accumsan efficitur. Fusce iacu| 
  241  |lis est et justo sollicitudin, s| 
  273  |ed porttitor augue sagittis. Mau| 
  305  |ris aliquam nisl nibh, sed tempu| 
  463  |molestie nisl elit, suscipit ege| 
  495  |stas ex aliquam ac. Donec dignis| 
  527  |sim, mauris nec malesuada pellen| 
  559  |tesque, ipsum sem porttitor est,| 
  591  | quis laoreet urna orci a leo. C| 
  623  |ras tincidunt porttitor sapien, | 
  655  |quis cursus metus pulvinar id. P|
```

So that's 16 blocks (or windows) of 32 bytes each for 512 bytes total that **Bob knows he doesn't need to send to Alice**. Bob then only needs to send the non-overlapping windows that aren't covered by the blocks above:

```
Offset   Bytes (as ASCII text)
----------------------------------------------
    0  |Proin finibus ullamcorper ante s| 
   33  |t amet egestas. Lorem ipsum dolo|
  330  |d tempus magna venenatis ac. Nul|
  363  |a ex metus, malesuada eget ultri|
  396  |ies vel, fermentum quis nisl. Et|
  429  |am ac venenatis tellus. Curabitu|
```

Not bad, eh?

Comment: clear explanation

Comment: very very impressive example!

Comment: Is it correct `33  |t amet egestas. Lorem ipsum dolo|`, not `32 |it amet egestas. Lorem ipsum dol|`

Comment: @chmin.seo What is your question?